PCA with two subspace
Given $N$ data points $[a_1,\dots,a_N]$, mathematically the PCA is to find a rank-r subspace $S$ such that the distances between these points and the subspace are minimized, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
S = \arg\min_L \{ \sum_j^N dist(a_j,L)^2: dim(L)=r \}.
\end{equation}
And this is solved by the SVD of $A = [a_1,\dots,a_N]$.
But what if we are seeking two subspaces $S_1,S_2$ with $dim(S_1) = r_1,dim(S_2) = r_2$ such that the distances between these points and the set $E= S_1 \bigcup S_2$ are minimized. This problem can be formulated as
\begin{align}
\min & \quad \sum_{j=1}^N \min\{dist(a_j,S_1)^2,dist(a_j,S_2)^2\}\\
subjected\ to & \quad dim(S_1)=r_1,dim(S_2)=r_2.
\end{align}
Or equivalently:
\begin{align}
\min & \quad \sum_{j=1}^N \min\{\|a_j-V V^Ta_j\|^2,\|a_j-U U^Ta_j\|^2\}\\
subjected\ to & \quad V^TV=I_{r_1},U^TU=I_{r_2}.
\end{align}
My question is: (1) is the above problem NP-hard? (2) if not, is there an efficient algorithm for it?
